# Mongoose not populating related array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I have followed the mongoose docs for populating related objects, everytime authSessions is empty. I can see in mongo sessions are being populated along with the related userId field. I have tried specifying ”path” and “model” options in the populate function as well but that didn’t work either. Anyone have any ideas?

````js
//Session.js
const SessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    sessionId: { type: String, index: true },
    createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    revoked: Boolean,
    revokedAt: Date,
    userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', index: true}
})
module.exports = mongoose.models.Session || mongoose.model('Session', SessionSchema);

//User.js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    username: { type: String, index: true },
    email: { type: String, index: true },
    password: String,
    registrationDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    authSessions: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Session'}]
})
module.exports = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

const user = await User.findById(session.userId).populate('authSessions').exec();
console.log(user) //authSessions is empty

{
  _id: new ObjectId("62b6ea393e042868caa68c7d"),
  username: 'asdfasdfasdf',
  email: 'testaskldjflk@djlkajdf.com',
  password: 'testaskldjflk@djlkajdf.com',
  authSessions: [],  //empty here always
  registrationDate: 2022-06-25T10:58:01.709Z,
  __v: 0
} ```
````

Comment: And you're pushing the proper `Session` documents into `user.authSessions` (and saving the user document afterwards)?

Comment: @robertklep So here is how im creating it,
            `const userSession = new Session({
                userId: user._id,
                sessionId: session_token,
            })
            await Session.create(userSession);`

Comment: @robertklep then here is the result from datagrip which im using to query mongo
`then here is the raw result from mongodb
[
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "62b6ef53ad9211e358babc45"},
    "__v": 0,
    "createdDate": {"$date": "2022-06-25T11:19:47.922Z"},
    "sessionId": "xx",
    "userId": {"$oid": "62b6ea393e042868caa68c7d"}
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "62b6f7f5e9a162a521bbc7f0"},
    "__v": 0,
    "createdDate": {"$date": "2022-06-25T11:56:37.991Z"},
    "sessionId": "xx",
    "userId": {"$oid": "62b6ea393e042868caa68c7d"}
  }
]`

Comment: Please add those comments to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB, and by extension `mongoose`, doesn't automatically create relations for you.

If you create a `Session` document, you need to explicitly add it to a `User` document if you want `populate` to work:

```
// create a new session document and save it
const userSession = new Session(…);
await userSession.save();

// !! update the user document and save it
user.authSessions.push(userSession);
await user.save();
```

Comment: That solved it, thanks so much. I had assumed it auto created the relationship, I’ll know now.